# Is it possible to make a device accessible exclusively by certain programs?

Tags: process, udev, devices, video, block-device

I have a device (a video card) that I need only two programs (expressed as paths, e.g. `/usr/bin/myprogram`) to access.

The device has a `/dev` file (e.g. `/dev/mydev1`), but I can also use other references if required (bus id, vendor/product id etc.).

Is there anything that I can do (e.g. `udev` rules), that prevents any program from access, except the ones I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic unix solution would be to create a system group (e.g. `groupadd -r vidcard`), then set the permissions of the device to only allow root and members of that group to access it. In Linux, that would take the form of an udev rule, as `/dev` is regenerated from scratch at every boot. The rule might look something like this:

```
 KERNEL=="mydev[0-9]*", MODE="0660", GROUP="vidcard"
```

Finally, the programs that need access would need to have their group owner set to `vidcard` and a setgid bit set. So:

```
chown root:vidcard /usr/bin/myprogram
chmod 2711 /usr/bin/myprogram  # this results in permissions -rwx--s--x
```

Regular users should *not* be given membership of the `vidcard` group. The only way they will be able to get that membership is by running `myprogram`.

If `myprogram` has a "run a shell" functionality or some other way for the user to run other programs of their choice, then those shells/other programs may inherit the `vidcard` group membership, unless `myprogram` is programmed to take steps to drop the extra privileges granted by the setgid bit before starting those other programs (`setregid()` in Linux).